# Need solution to remove duplicate code in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using this right now to clear a tic tac toe table on Microsoft Windows Forms

```
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = true;
            button3.Enabled = true;
            button4.Enabled = true;
            button5.Enabled = true;
            button6.Enabled = true;
            button7.Enabled = true;
            button8.Enabled = true;
            button9.Enabled = true;
            button1.Text = "";
            button2.Text = "";
            button3.Text = "";
            button4.Text = "";
            button5.Text = "";
            button6.Text = "";
            button7.Text = "";
            button8.Text = "";
            button9.Text = "";
```

but it's too long so I wanted to use a for loop like this

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
   button[i].Enable = true;
   button[i].Text = "";
}
```

but it doesn't work so could anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Why not put all of your buttons in an array? Then you can access them as array elements. `var buttons = new[] { button1, button2, button3, ... }`

Comment: "it doesn't work" is ***not*** a valid error description. also: did you actually _put_ your buttons in an array?

Comment: (You can get fancy with writing code to generate your buttons, so you never even have `button1` and you go straight for an array, but that's a step up: start simple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you are thinking, but you cannot dynamically change the name of the variable you are trying to edit in a for loop like that.

In a `for` loop, it will iterate through a starting value until it reaches a stopping condition. `for` loops are great for when you have a [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) like a `List` or an `Array` where you can enumerate through to get or set values.

The code you have for the `for` loop is starting to enumerate through either an `Array` or `List` that has a name of `button`. To fix this, I recommend to add the buttons to an `Array` and then you can use a `foreach` loop to set the values:

```
foreach (Button button in buttons){
    button.Enabled = true;
    button.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: This solution worked very well with my code and was very helpful, I hadn't used an Array for the buttons which I see now will make a lot of the work throughout the program I'm making much easier and more legible. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

you can iterate over **Controls** array of parent of buttons, for example you can move all buttons to a **Panel** and use foreach to iterate over all controls inside it:

```
foreach(var control in Panel1.Controls) {
    if (control is Button button)
    {
        button.Text = "";
        button.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems fragile: the order of the buttons might end up mattering to OP, but I can't see that being defined here

Comment: It's also heavy-handed. It's unlikely that *all* buttons on the form are candidates for this treatment. "OK" and "Cancel" buttons, if the form has them, would not, for example.